# Error getting value from PHP with JSON

Tags: php, json

I have a database that have a table with 2 columns : `ID(int)`,`Message(text)`.

I need to get values with:

```
ID (select * from table where ID=1)
```

However, I only get the ID and the message show me NULL value (parsing with JSON).

```
<?php 

//Getting the requested id
$ID = $_GET['ID'];

//Importing database
require_once('dbConnect.php');

//Creating sql query with where clause to get an specific employee
$sql = "SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE ID=$ID";

//getting result 
$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

//pushing result to an array 
$result = array();
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
array_push($result,array(
        "ID"=>$row[0],
        "MESSAGE"=>$row[1],


//displaying in json format 
echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));

mysqli_close($con);
```

?>

And this what i get :

```
{"result":[{"ID":"1","MESSAGE":null,}]}
```

Comment: There's not enough information in this question. How are you parsing the result of the query into a JSON? Could you paste the snippet of code that does that? Once done that, what should be the expected outcome?

Comment: I add the code in the question .

Comment: Use var_dump($row) to see the array. I think you are getting wrong column with $row[1] check it out first

Comment: no , it's right , i also add other columns and get all of them , but i never get the message , i think because it has a lot of characters , can the lenght of message make him appear Null ?

Comment: This is not even alid php code. Some `)` is missing ... at last.

Comment: Thanks All , i found the problem , i use some special characters in the message , that's why he doesn't appear .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were syntax errors I fixed for you. Other things which need improvement:

a) **Don't ever use raw `$_GET` data** within sql statements! At least convert the data to the proper type (int). Have a look at prepared statements to avoid sql injection.

b) Only add data to `$result` if something is found by your query

```
<?php 

//Getting the requested id
$ID = (int) $_GET['ID']; // Cast value to int to prevent sql injection!

//Importing database
require_once('dbConnect.php');

//Creating sql query with where clause to get an specific employee
$sql = "SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE ID=$ID";

//getting result 
$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

//pushing result to an array 
$result = array();
if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
  array_push(
    $result,
    array(
        "ID"=>$row[0],
        "MESSAGE"=>$row[1]
    )
  );
  //displaying in json format 
  echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));

} else {
  // Noting found
}

mysqli_close($con);
```